# .htaccess mod_deflate not working for dynamic URL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, symfony

I have a URL as follows `www.example.com/fr_FR` the curl return type is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2017 10:35:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=img4385scm6ldm6vngtntsrou1; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: FirstVisit=1; expires=Wed, 18-Oct-2017 10:35:20 GMT; Max-Age=172800; path=/; httponly
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

My `.htaccess` contains the following directive:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/rss+xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
```

The issue is that the particular URL is not being gzipped, however, if I access a `.html` file or if I do add the `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html` directly in my apache vhost the gzip works:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

For information in my vhost `AllowOverride` is set to `All`.

What is wrong with the URL `/fr_FR`, why is it not being gziped even though the `Content-Type` is `text/html`?

**Update1:**

For information my site is a symfony2 site

Comment: Try removing the `<IfModule>` wrapper around that directive. "`AllowOverride` is set to `All`" - in the appropriate `<Directory>` container?

Comment: @MrWhite Hello, I did remove the `<IfModue>` wrapper but the issue is the same. Yes `AllowOveride` is set to `All` in the concerned `<Directory>` block

Comment: Try to enable enable GZIP compression as described at https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/set-up-wordpress-with-optimal-htaccess-settings/

Comment: @RoseHosting That link doesn't offer anything that isn't already mentioned in the question? (It also looks very self-promoting.)

Answer (score 0):

apache docs(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype) suggest that AddOutputFilterByType may fail partially or completely in some cases. Also this directive is deprecated in apache 2.1 and later. Since you said .html works  can you try:

```
AddType text/html .html
```